# redirecting to localhost dashboard instead of project root

Tags: .htaccess

I have a site in localhost - `ourallnews`. I want to redirect all keyword - `index, index.php, index.html` to site root - `localhost/ourallnews/`. I have applied following rule in `.htaccess` but it is redirected to - `localhost/dashboard/`. How to fix it ?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /ourallnews/
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.(php|html?)$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /category(?:\.php)?\?cat=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)$ category.php?cat=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a `RewriteBase` then just use a relative link while redirecting:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /ourallnews/

RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.(?:php|html?)$ $1 [R=301,NC,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /category(?:\.php)?\?cat=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ category.php?cat=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Make sure to clear browser cache or use a new browser for your testing.

Comment: you are genius regarding .htaccess rules. I find your other answers in this site well-explained and helpful.  Thanks again